# How to put a mathematical object like tensor above a node on a curved line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a curved line and put a tensor above and below a node on it, something like this:
[image]

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tensor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]

   \draw[line width=4pt] (0,0) ..controls (2,2) and (5,-1) .. (10,2);
    node[pos=0.5,below right, inner xsep=-1ex] {$\tensor{g}{_a_b}$}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I know that I'm mixing it up with something else, but I do not enough time.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that even worked. You're ending the `\draw` path with the semicolon before you add the `node`. Move the semicolon to after the `node` and it's fine.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tensor}    
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\draw[line width=4pt] (0,0) ..controls (2,2) and (5,-1) .. (10,2)
    node[pos=0.5,below] {$\tensor{g}{_a_b}$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Something closer to your sketch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) ..controls (2,2) and (5,-1) .. (10,2)
    node[fill,circle,minimum size=8pt,inner sep=0pt,pos=0.4,label=below:{$\tensor{g}{_a_b}$},label=above:{$t=0$}] {}
    node[fill,circle,minimum size=8pt,inner sep=0pt,pos=0.8,label=below:{$\tensor{g}{_a_b}$},label=above:{$t$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I do not understand "minimum size=4pt". That has no influence on result.

Comment: @H.B. Sorry, a small glitch on my side. It does have an effect, for sufficiently large values. However, by default you have an `inner sep` that is larger (0.333em), so the node will be larger than `4pt` anyway. In the updated code I set the inner sep to zero, making this more predictable.